# Operational error at / no such table: tasks_task even after creating a table

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-models

Here is my html file of landing page.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="center-column">

        <form method="POST" action="/">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.title}}
            <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="Create Task">
        </form>

        <div class="todo-list">

        {% for task in tasks %}
            <div class="item-row">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'update_task' task.id %}">Update</a>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'delete' task.id %}">Delete</a>

                {% if task.complete == True %}
                <strike>{{task}}</strike>
                {% else %}
                <span>{{task}}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is Models.py file where a table is created

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Error i am getting

```
OperationalError at /
no such table: tasks_task
C:\Users\91870\Desktop\Django\todo\tasks\templates\tasks\list.html, error at line 15
```

line 15 is

```
 {% for task in tasks %}
```

here is views.py file

```
def index(request):
    tasks = Task.objects.all()

    form = TaskForm()

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    return render(request, 'tasks/list.html', {'tasks':tasks, 'form':form})
```

It was working when i haven't applied the css but now it isn't.
Can someone please help me with this

Comment: Have you applied all your migrations?

Comment: Yes, i did applied all of the migrations

Comment: @MeL Can you please help me?

Comment: Try deleting all your migrations and then running them again